# how i add View Array in my scrollView(in Android support)?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

i am new App Developer with Titanium. i want to create a window base application. whose run on iphone or ipad or android platform. 
When i run application on iphone than run properly, but when i run on Android than it show a msg (Unexpected Error) and after this it is close.

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({   
   backgroundColor : '#f0f0f0',      
}); 

var view1 = Titanium.UI.createView({    
height  : 100,  
width   : 100,  
backgroundColor : '#ff0000',
borderColor  : '#000',

}); 

var scrollView1 = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({    
contentHeight   : 150,  
backgroundColor : '#00ff00',

});

var abc = new Array();

abc[0] = 'images/img.png',

abc[1] = 'images/img1.png',

scrollView1.add(abc); 

view1.add(scrollView1); 

win1.add(view1);

win1.open();
```

how i add Array in my scroll view.
in array i store (images path)

please help me,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It work properly in iphone or ipad, But not in Android...

Comment: Does it show any line number?

Comment: no, its flesh alert and have msg is 
<application name> has stopped unexpectedly, Please Try Again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
var array = new Array();
array[0] = 'image path';
array[1] = 'image path';

for(a = 0; a<array.length;a++){
var lab1            = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
   backgroundImage      : array1[a],
   height           : 75,
   width            : 75,
   backgroundColor          : '#712347',
   borderRadius         : '10',
   zIndex           : 11,
   });

scrLabel.add(lab1);
}
```

I, Think this is supported, for you.

Comment: Use an ImageView not a label to display images: Ti.UI.createImageView not Ti.UI.createLabel

Comment: ok Sorry, for that, 
I have some problem in Using UI object.
BUt, i have Logics
Thanks very Much for ur Reply...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({   
   backgroundColor : '#f0f0f0'      
}); 

var view1 = Titanium.UI.createView({    
height  : 100,  
width   : 100,  
backgroundColor : '#ff0000',
borderColor  : '#000'

}); 

var scrollView1 = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({    
contentHeight   : 150,  
backgroundColor : '#00ff00'

});

var abc = ['images/img.png','images/img1.png'];

scrollView1.add(abc); 

view1.add(scrollView1); 

win1.add(view1);

win1.open();
```

Comment: what is different between both, i think this is same and
same msg flashed

Comment: I removed extra comas in the objects and placed ; in arrays.

Comment: no, my problem as it is.
my application is properly run on iphone simulator but problem in android

Comment: Remove the array code and check it is working or not? Remove these lines var abc = new Array();
abc[0] = 'images/img.png';
abc[1] = 'images/img1.png';
scrollView1.add(abc);

Comment: ya, when i make comment (//scrollView1.add(abc);)
than run properly in both simulator (iphone or android)

Comment: when i add the array in scrollView than This problem is occur,
if, i add another object just like button or imageview than run properly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7690/discussion-between-mrt-and-muhammad-zeeshan)

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'add' an array to a window object - 'add' only takes Titanium Proxy objects - things returned from Ti.UI.create.... methods - as the argument.  See my commented code below:

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({   
  backgroundColor : '#f0f0f0',      
}); 

var view1 = Titanium.UI.createView({    
  height  : 100,  
  width   : 100,  
  backgroundColor : '#ff0000',
  borderColor  : '#000',
}); 

var scrollView1 = Titanium.UI.createScrollView({    
  contentHeight   : 150,  
  backgroundColor : '#00ff00',
});

var abc = ['images/img.png', 'images/img1.png'];

// if you want the image paths available as a variable, just set it
scrollView1.abc = abc;
// But I don't understand why you are doing this - you can just access the paths
// from abc directly 

view1.add(scrollView1); 

// You were adding the scroll view twice: win1.add(scrollView1);
// You want to add the view:
win1.add(view1);

win1.open();
```

Comment: Hello, I want to show my all picture with thumbnails view whose found in my picture gallery. 
how i can do, plz, help me.

Comment: (Note: its run properly in iphone simulator but not on Android.)

Comment: The fact that any images are showing in iOS is strange.  To display images, you need to create a ImageView and add it to the ScrollView.  Have you downloaded the Kitchen Sink and had a look at the code in it?  It would help you understand Titanium much better.

Comment: Thanks a lots, 
This is very use for me(Kitchen Sink), Thanks vary much for your response ..

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = new Array();
array[0] = 'image path';
array[1] = 'image path';

for(a = 0; a<array.length;a++){
var lab1            = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
   backgroundImage      : array1[a],
   height           : 75,
   width            : 75,
   backgroundColor          : '#712347',
   borderRadius         : '10',
   zIndex           : 11,
   });

scrLabel.add(lab1);
}
```